# Combining Averageif and Averagea: take a conditional average treating blanks as 0

Tags: google-sheets

I need to calculate an average conditioned over a range that can contain empty cells or the empty strings ("").

The formula [AVERAGEIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529?hl=en) like [AVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615) ignore the empty cells.
The formula AVERAGE, has an 'alter ego' that converts text cells to 0 value: [AVERAGEA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093617)

I haven't found a formula that joins AVERAGEIF with AVERAGEA. Anyone have an idea to resolve the problem and treat empty cells as 0?

Comment: AVERAGEA does _not_ treat empty cells as 0! Only non-empty text cells.

Answer (score 3):

You can add 0 to convert empty strings and blank spaces to 0. Then use `AVERAGE`. Example:

```
=average(arrayformula(A1:A15 + 0))
```

calculates the average of all numbers, treating "" and blanks as 0.

One needs `arrayformula` here to handle adding 0 to each element of the range.

Comment: Hi Meta, I changed the formula following your suggestion ( "=iferror(AVERAGEIF(D2:O2,TRUE,arrayformula(D33:O33 + 0)),0) "); in D2:02 I have a range of False/True and the range of average must be D33:O33. now it return 0 (answer of ifError); the error that return averageif is N/A Argument must be a range; where is the error? Thanks   a lot

Comment: @cicciocappuccio: Follow up questions should be posted as new questions.