# Calculate weekly average given only year and week number

Tags: google-sheets

This is a school assignment, though unfortunately I'm either overthinking the question or this is significantly easier than I think.

Starting off here is a link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jDFzitEGi319i6hUjqjJDF8nYZ8qm09-ieMGHk2T7AA/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to calculate a weekly average from [Point Spread], though column A, B only offer a year and a week number. What would be the most efficient to tackle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the best way"? What formula did you try? (questions should contain all the relevant details, like the formula). Reference [ask].

Comment: By best way I mean a formula for the most efficient method. I've looked at related questions to create a formula, though they all have proper date formats and don't exactly work with this spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I don't have experience in spreadsheets so I do not know how to try it myself.

Comment: Sum the point spread of each week then use the avg function?

Comment: @SCramphorn Is there a formula to calculate it more efficiently? There's 737 entries in this sheet itself, in the case it would have thousands doing it manually seems very inefficient and time consuming.

Comment: @Nom just working it out now. thinking along the lines of: 

`=if(B7 <> B6 & B7 = B8,"calculate avg","print nothing")`

Comment: @Nom: The way to solve the lack of experience is by trying to solve things by yourself and asking good questions. A good question includes a brief but complete description of what you tried, a summary of what you found that is relevant for the question an a brief explanation of why doesn't work for you.

Comment: A related question on [webapps.se]: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91209/conditional-average-with-a-function

Comment: A related question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972288/combining-averageif-and-averagea-take-a-conditional-average-treating-blanks-as

Comment: So do you just need the average per year and week? Why not use a pivot table? Or a query?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're supposed to calculate the average of Point Spread for each distinct values of the year and the week, so for week 1 of 1998, you would calculate the average of the Point Spread on the first 16 rows.

Comment: Though then there's week 2 with a different amount of values, week 3 with different values. Is there a faster way to do it instead of counting =Sum(B2:B16), =Sum(B16:B31), =Sum(B32:43) ... all the way to =Sum(B723:B737)

Comment: there must be a better way