# Excel AVERAGEIFS like formula which treats text as 0 and not ignore them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there anyway to use `AVERAGEIF` or a similar function that treats text value as 0 and not just ignore them. Something similar to `AVERAGEA` function, but with multiple criteria?

I saw a similar question here which wanted to treat blanks or empty cells as 0. The answer suggested to use array formulas to add 0 to it. Not sure if it holds for other texts as well.

Comment: The similar question can be found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972288/combining-averageif-and-averagea-take-a-conditional-average-treating-blanks-as)

Comment: does this help? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the document for AVERAGEIF as well which treats texts as 0

Comment: FYI, down-voted your question for not showing sample data with expected output, and also not showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do NOT want to count blanks, you can use:

```
=SUM(A1:A10)/COUNTA(A1:A10)
```

(*If you wanted to count blanks, something like `sum(rng)/rows(rng)` would do it*)

You can use a similar technique to include criteria for `AVERAGEIF`

For example, given:

[image]

If you want to average all the values in Column A where `a` is in Column B:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B10,"a",A1:A10)/COUNTIF(B1:B10,"a")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be similar to the other link:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(--A1:A10,0))
```

It is an array formula and with Excel to confirm an array formula one must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

One Note:  This will treat blanks as `0` also, so make sure it only refers to the data set desired.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rohan's post, I personally would break it down to see how many strings are pushing down your average. But if you want it all in one cell:

***That is an asterisk inside the double quotes***

one cell: =SUM(E1:E10)/(COUNTIF(E1:E10,"*")+COUNTIF(E1:E10,"*<>*"))

break down:
Non-Numeric: COUNTIF(E1:E10,"*****")
Numeric: COUNTIF(E1:E10,"**<>***")

spreadsheet link
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOqPt.jpg)